# UnitTest a PHP CodeIgniter Controller that calls a model

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm testing my CodeIgniter project with PHPUnit Testing framework (`CITest.php`). When the function `test_model()`, calls the model directly to get the details of an user, it works perfectly. But when I do the same via a controller by calling the function `test_controller()`, it does not output anything (When I debugged, the model itself doesn't gets called). I even verfied if the post data is passed correctly by creating a function `test_post_data()`. Am I missing something?

I could only find online resources to test the mdoel directly or a controller separately. But I couldn't find any useful link which calls a controller that triggers the model.

**CITest.php**

```
class CITest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  private $CI;
  public function setUp()
  {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('Test_model');
    $this->model = $this->CI->My_model; // load the model
    $this->auth = new Test_controller; // load the controller
  }

  public test_model() {
    $user_id = 6;
    print_r($this->model->getUserData($user_id));
  }

  public test_post_data() {
    $_POST['useR_id'] = 22;
    print_r($this->model->check_post_data());
  }

  public test_controller() {
    $_POST['useR_id'] = 22;
    print_r($this->model->get_user_data());
  }
}
```

**Test_controller.php**

```
class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Test_model');
    }

    public function check_post_data() {
        return $this->input->post();
    }

    public function get_user_data() {
        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
        return $this->Test_model->getUserData($user_id);
    }
}
```

**Test_model.php**

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getUserData($user_id) {
        return $this->db->select("*")
                    ->from("users")
                    ->where("user_id", $user_id)
                    ->get()->result_array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in `CITest.php`

`public test_controller() {
    $_POST['useR_id'] = 22;
    print_r($this->model->get_user_data());
  }`

should be like the following?

`public test_controller() {
    $_POST['useR_id'] = 22;
    print_r($this->auth->get_user_data());
  }`